# MariaDB select only results greater than

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, adminer

I have a query that looks like the following:

```
select uid,leadcount,salescount,leadcount/salescount as diff from 
(
SELECT x.uid, COUNT(*) leadcount, COUNT(DISTINCT x.fid)
FROM total_leads AS x
WHERE x.uid BETWEEN 1 AND 5
GROUP BY x.uid
) t1 left join 
(
SELECT ud.UserId, COUNT(*) salescount, COUNT(DISTINCT ud.SalesID)
FROM total_sales AS ud
WHERE ud.UserId BETWEEN 1 AND 5
GROUP BY ud.UserID
) t2 on t1.uid=t2.UserId
```

It results in:

[image]

I'm trying to display only results where `diff` is greater than `2.5` (so in this case only `uid` **5** should be visible on output).

I tried using `WHERE diff >= 2.5` but I got *"You have an error in your SQL syntax"*.

> **[Working example of MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/370b52)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL and MariaDB, you can just add a `HAVING` clause to the end of the query:

```
HAVING diff >= 2.5
```

This acts like a `WHERE` but can  use the alias.

Answer (score 2):

Just repeat the original expression in the `WHERE` clause rather than using an alias:

```
SELECT uid leadcount, salescount, leadcount/salescount AS diff
FROM
(
    ...
) t
WHERE leadcount/salescount >= 2.5;
```

The problem with referring to `diff` in the `WHERE` clause is that it is not yet available.  Also, see Gordon's answer for another option, assuming you don't plan to ever aggregate.  But, using `HAVING` is only an option on MySQL or MariaDB.

Comment: @ctfd It is because often the `WHERE` clause will execute _before_ the alias has actually been assigned.  `diff` simply does not exist when the `WHERE` clause happens.